A regular polygon of $2023$ sides is inscribed in a circle of unit radius. Prove that its side and all its diagonals have irrational lengths

A regular polygon having $2023$ sides is inscribed in a circle of unit radius. Prove that all its side and diagonals have irrational lengths.

I tried proving this by taking a base case of $n=3$, for which I got irrational lengths, for $n=4$, I did not get irrational lengths, on some more generalization, I got that for an odd $n$, we get irrational lengths.
Hence, we can claim for a polygon having $2023$ sides will have irrational lengths.
However, I am not able to devise a rigorous proof around this claim and being very closely related to the plotting of roots of unity on a unit circle, I suspect of a complicated proof around the De moivre's theorem.

Let $P$ be a regular polygon with $2023$ sides whose vertices lie on the unit circle. We can think of $P$ as being drawn in the complex plane. Without loss of generality, we may assume $V_k = e^{2\pi i k/2023}$ for $k\in [2023]$ are the vertices of $P$. Demonstrating that the sides and diagonals of $P$ are irrational is equivalent to showing that the pairwise distance between any two vertices of $P$ is irrational. The distance between two vertices $V_j$ and $V_k$ is $$|e^{2\pi i j/2023}-e^{2\pi i k/2023}|,$$ which looks like the exponential definition of the sine function; let us make use of that. But first, note that
$$
e^{2\pi i j/2023}-e^{2\pi i k/2023} = e^{\pi i(j+k)/2023}\left(e^{\pi i(j- k)/2023}-e^{-\pi i(j- k)/2023}\right).
$$
Now, $e^{\pi i(j+k)/2023}$ is just a point on the unit circle, so $|e^{\pi i(j+k)/2023}|=1$. Moreover, recall that $\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$. Hence
\begin{align}
\left|e^{2\pi i j/2023}-e^{2\pi i k/2023}\right| &= \left|e^{\pi i(j+k)/2023}\left(e^{\pi i(j- k)/2023}-e^{-\pi i(j- k)/2023}\right)\right|\\
&=\left|2i\sin\left({\tfrac{\pi(j-k)}{2023}}\right)\right|\\
&= 2\sin\left({\tfrac{\pi(j-k)}{2023}}\right).
\end{align}
Let us ignore the factor of $2$ and focus on $\sin\left({\frac{\pi(j-k)}{2023}}\right)$. We need the following claim, which follows from Niven's theorem. We include a proof of the claim. A more elementary proof using a cosine double angle formula, written by Jahnel, can be found here.

Claim: Let $r$ be a rational number. If $\sin(r\pi)$ is rational, then $\sin(r\pi)\in \{0, \pm \frac{1}{2}, \pm 1\}$.
Proof. It is sufficient to prove $\cos(r\pi) \in \{0, \pm \frac{1}{2}, \pm 1\}$ since $\cos(r\pi) = \sin\left((\frac{1}{2}-r)\pi\right)$. Suppose $\cos(r\pi)$ is rational, and let $r = \frac{m}{n}$ be a rational number in lowest terms. Notice that
$$ (e^{i\pi r})^{2n} =
 e^{i2\pi m} = 1, $$
so $e^{i\pi r}$ is a root of the polynomial $z^{2n}-1$, a monic polynomial with integer coefficients. Thus $e^{i\pi r}$ is an algebraic integer. The same holds for $e^{-i\pi r}$. By the exponential definition of cosine, we get
$$ 2\cos(r\pi) =
 e^{i\pi r} + e^{-i\pi r}. $$
Since the sum of algebraic integers is again an algebraic integer, $2\cos(r\pi)$ is an algebraic integer. Moreover, $A\cap \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Z}$, where $A$ is the set of algebraic integers. Thus $2\cos(r\pi)$ must be an integer. Because $-1 \leq \cos(r\pi) \leq 1$, the only possible values for $2\cos(r\pi)$ are in $\mathbb{Z}\cap [-2,2]$. We conclude that $ \cos(r\pi) \in \{0, \pm \frac{1}{2}, \pm 1\}$, as desired.

The rest of the proof is elementary algebra and trigonometry. Without loss of generality, assume $j>k$, so $0<\tfrac{\pi(j-k)}{2023}<2\pi$. If $\sin\left({\tfrac{\pi(j-k)}{2023}}\right)=0$, then $\tfrac{\pi(j-k)}{2023}$ has to be an integer multiple of $\pi$, which is impossible, as $0<j-k<2023$. If $\sin\left({\tfrac{\pi(j-k)}{2023}}\right)=\pm 1$, then $\tfrac{\pi(j-k)}{2023} = \tfrac{\pi}{2}+l\pi$ for $l\in \{0,1\}$. But then $l=\frac{j-k}{2023}-\frac{1}{2}$, which is not integral as $2023$ is odd, a contradiction. Similarly, if $\sin\left({\frac{\pi(j-k)}{2023}}\right)=\pm \frac{1}{2}$, then $\tfrac{\pi(j-k)}{2023} = \tfrac{\pi}{6}+l\pi$ or $\tfrac{\pi(j-k)}{2023} = \tfrac{5\pi}{6}+l\pi$; both lead to contradictions in similar ways to the previous case. We conclude that the sides and diagonals of $P$ all have irrational lengths, as desired.

This isn't really a proof unless it also contains a proof of Niven's theorem.

@TonyK fair enough. I've updated my answer, I hope it's better.

Very nice!${}{}$

Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for

Any side or diagonal length of a regular $2023$ sided polygon can be represented as $|w-1|$ where $w$ is a $2023$th root of unity other than $1$.
Suppose $|w-1| = q\in\mathbb Q$. We have
$$\begin{aligned}
|w-1| = q
&\implies (w-1)(\bar w-1) = q^2\\
&\implies (w-1)(\bar w-1)w = q^2 w\\
&\implies (w-1)(1-w) = q^2w\\
&\implies -w^2+2w-1 = q^2w\\
&\implies w^2 +(q^2-2)w+1 = 0
\end{aligned}$$
Because $2023$ is odd, $w$ is not rational (in fact, it is not even real), thus, its minimal polynomial must be $q(x) = x^2+(q^2-2)x+1$. We can conclude our proof right away with the help of a simple lemma.

Lemma. The minimal polynomial for the $n$th primitive roots of unity have degree $\varphi(n)$.

The minimal polynomial for the $n$th primitive roots of unity is the $n$th Cyclotomic Polynomial. Here, $\varphi$ denotes Euler's Totient Function.
The only positive integers $n$ such that $\varphi(n) = 2$ are $n =3, 4, 6$. Therefore, the lemma tell us $w$ must be a $3$th, $4$th or $6$th root of unity. This is impossible as none of these values actually divide $2023$.
The same proof works for any odd positive integer. Furthermore, we have shown every side and diagonal length of an odd sided regular polygon inscribed in a unit circle cannot be the square root of a rational number.

An elementary solution:
Create an isosceles triangle by drawing two radii from the center of the circle to the ends of the side/diagonal; the vertex angle $\theta$ is some integer multiple of $2\pi/2023$ strictly between $0$ and $\pi$. Using right-triangle trigonometry, the length in question is $2\sin(\theta/2)$. If this length is rational, then so is $2\cos(\theta) = 2-(2\sin(\theta/2)^2$.
Repeatedly use the double-angle formula $2\cos(2\theta) = (2\cos(\theta))^2-2$ to see that $2\cos(2^k\theta)$ is rational for each natural number $k$. Each of these angles is an integer multiple of $2\pi/2023$; since there's only a finite number of such angles (after taking out multiples of $2\pi$), this sequence repeats at some point.
Let $x = 2\cos(2^k\theta)$ be an element of this sequence that repeats. Then from the repeated use of the double-angle formula we have
$$ (((x^2-2)^2-2)^2-2)^2\cdots-2 = x.$$
The left-hand side minus the right-hand side is a polynomial with leading coefficient $1$ and constant coefficient $\pm 2$, so by the rational root theorem the only possibilities for rational solutions are $x = \pm 1, \pm 2$. This means that $2^k\theta$ would have to be an integer multiple of $\pi/3$. But it isn't.
